# Not able to access DynamoDB when using local Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I tried to connect to `dynamodb` and have started the server locally my server is running in local but I am not able to access it.

1. By using docker.
2. By running exe file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Local dynamodb hosts its web shell at `/shell`. Try `localhost:8000/shell`.

You can also interact with it using the AWS CLI.

```
  aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint http://localhost:8000
```

You will need some credentials configured (the CLI will fail without them), but they don't need to be valid.

This command will list any tables you have created.

Note that since local-dynamodb was started with sharedDb=false the AWS access key id used to connect to the database will be used to keep data separated based on the access key id.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't help., Is there any  other way thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with docker on windows. Perhaps you need to try http://192.168.99.100:8000 (The IP address docker's default machine is using.)

Answer (score 0):

What Docker are you using there and why in MINGW?  You can just run that command locally from a traditional cmd prompt and it should work.  Did you modify your docker default network at all?